# error when compiling sqlite

Tags: compiling, sqlite3

I received this error when compiling sqlite:

> Makefile:743: recipe for target 'alter.lo' failed make[4]: ***
>   [alter.lo] Error 1 CMakeFiles/external_sqlite.dir/build.make:113:
>   recipe for target
>   'build/sqlite/src/external_sqlite-stamp/external_sqlite-build' failed
>   make[3]: ***
>   [build/sqlite/src/external_sqlite-stamp/external_sqlite-build] Error 2
>   CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1427: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/external_sqlite.dir/all' failed make[2]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/external_sqlite.dir/all] Error

Are there any dependencies that I missed? How do I solve this error? Thanks!

Comment: I think you have supplied too little of the error output. Can you add a bit more of the error message?

Comment: Why not use the version in the repositories: `sudo apt install sqlite3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.